# how can i compare start date and end date with foundation datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, compare

i like to compare my start date and end date with foundation datepicker.

My compare is:

```
if(enddate < startdate){
  error
}
```

here my Code:

```
jQuery("#startDate,#endDate").fdatepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
    language: 'de',
    todayHighlight: true
});

var startdate = "";
var enddate = "";

jQuery("#startDate").change(function() {

    startdate = jQuery('#startDate').val();
    console.log(startdate);
});

jQuery("#endDate").change(function() {

    enddate = jQuery('#endDate').val();
    console.log(enddate);
});

// compare 
if(enddate < startdate){
    console.log("error");
}
```

An here my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RDB76/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to bind this to some sort of an event (for instance a
   click on the submit button)
2. You'll need to convert the dates into a format that you can compare them in

here's the  updated code to show you what I mean

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-row field_text">
    <label for="startdaum" class="required">Start Date *:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startdatum" class="input_text date">
</div>

<div class="form-row field_text ">
        <label for="enddatum" class="required" id="">End Date *:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="endDate" name="enddatum" class="input_text">
</div>

<div class="form-row field_text">
         <label for="interval" class="required">interval:</label><br>
         <div class="select-box">

               <select class="" name="interval" id="intervall" >
                            <option value="0">no </option>
                            <option value="1">all da</option>
                            <option value="7">weekly</option>
                            <option value="14">all 2 weeks</option>
               </select>
         </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**JS**

```
jQuery("#startDate,#endDate").fdatepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
    language: 'de',
    todayHighlight: true
});

var startdate = "";
var enddate = "";

jQuery("#startDate").change(function() {

    startdate = jQuery('#startDate').val();
    console.log(startdate);
});

jQuery("#endDate").change(function() {

    enddate = jQuery('#endDate').val();
    console.log(enddate);
});

// compare 
jQuery('input[type=submit]').on('click', function () {
   startdate = process(startdate);
   enddate = process(enddate);
    console.log(startdate);
    console.log(enddate);
if(enddate < startdate){
    console.log("error");
}    
});

function process(date){
   var parts = date.split(".");
   return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}
```

Here's a working [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RDB76/8/)